# Possible to pass multiple inline values to an aggregation function?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I can call an aggregation function directly on a scalar literal value, such as:

```
select SUM(2);
┌────────┐
│ sum(2) │
╞════════╡
│      2 │
└────────┘
Elapsed: 1 ms
```

Is there any way to pass multiple inline values into an aggregation function, such as:

```
SELECT SUM(1,2,3) 
SELECT SUM([1,2,3])
SELECT SUM((1,2,3))
etc.
```

I know I can do this with a CTE or a `VALUES` clause or something else in the `FROM`, but I'm wondering if it can be used directly without a `FROM` clause. Actual DB doesn't matter here.

Comment: What's your dbms? mysql <> postgresl

Comment: `Actual DB doesn't matter here` ... actually, the DB _totally_ matters here, because some databases, such as Postgres, support array syntax, and might be able to do what you need, while others, such as MySQL, do not support such syntax.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sure postgres is fine. I'm testing it on Postgres, BigQuery, and Snowflake intermittently.

Comment: But why did you need `I'm wondering if it can be used directly without a FROM clause` is there any reason? otherwise I think `UNNEST` function is find

Comment: @D-Shih just doing some dynamic sql generation and would be simpler doing it right there, but if that's not possible then yes `UNNEST` is the next best think I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function with `variadic` to pass multiple parameters. In the background such an argument is an array.

```
create function my_sum(variadic p_numbers integer[])
  returns bigint
as
$$
  select sum(i)
  from unnest(p_numbers) as u(i);
$$
language sql
stable;
```

You can then call it using

```
select my_sum(1,2,3);
select my_sum(2,7);
```